# Submodules of $\mathbb{Q}\oplus \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I'm trying to find a description of all the submodules of $\mathbb{Q}\oplus \mathbb{Q}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-module, particularly the simple and maximal ones.
So far I am happy that $\mathbb{Q}\oplus 0$ and $0\oplus \mathbb{Q}$ are clear simple, maximal submodules. Now I think $(a,b)\mathbb{Q}$ where $a \neq b$ and $a,b \neq 0$ are also submodules. I think these are also maximal and simple but I'm not too sure how to show this.

Comment: Have you studied linear algebra of vector spaces? $\Bbb{Q}$ is a field, and $\Bbb{Q} \oplus \Bbb{Q}$ has dimension $2$. Do you know what are its subspaces of dimension $1$?

Comment: So could I view $(a \ b)\mathbb{Q}$ as a 'line' in $\mathbb{Q}\oplus \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Yes: it is indeed a line. And a subspace of $\Bbb{Q}^2$ must be a line (dimension $1$), or $0$.

Comment: ah ok, I see now. Thanks.